# React Native iOS module Pod dependency

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to use a dependency installed from a Podfile inside my custom native module, but I'm not having success. When I install my pods I can use them normally inside my project, but looks like the Library (a React Native native module) can't use the installed pod.

Just to remember: my Podfile is ok, I can even work with the installed dependency in the main project, but not in the Native Module.

I always get the "Module XXX not found" error in the .m/.swift file inside the custom Library.

Am I missing something? Sorry if I'm misexplaining, I'm sleepy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your native module is being imported by dragging in the .xcproj into your main project.

In the native module's project: Go to `Build Settings > Header Search Paths` and add: `{PATH_TO_IOS_BASE}/Pods/{NAME_OF_POD}` and set it to `recursive` you should then be able to import it from your `ObjC` files.

Note: You can also just drag the respective pod folder into the `Search Header Paths`.

For example for a native module installed through `npm` I'd use: `$(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/{NAME_OF_POD}`.

Comment: `$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/**` i added the following to the header search paths and still didn't work.  used 3 `../` instead of 4 because for my project that gets me out of `node_modules`